# Using Helm to deploy MariaDB to cluster ended up with FORBIDDEN error

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying MariaDB on my k8s cluster (Docker-desktop version) running on MacBook (M2 chip). Since the M2 chip is an ARM64 architecture, so I try to find the matching MariaDB image.

I found [this one](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/groundhog2k/mariadb/0.1.4).

So, I use Helm to deploy it by:

1. Add the helm repo

```
helm repo add groundhog2k https://groundhog2k.github.io/helm-charts/
```

2. Install MariaDB:

```
helm upgrade --install my-local-cluster groundhog2k/mariadb \
      --version 0.8.0 \
      --namespace mariadb \
      --set auth.rootPassword="my-root-pwd" \
      --set master.persistence.size=10Gi \
      --set auth.username="my-usr-name" \
      --set auth.password="my-pwd"
```

But I receive this error:

```
UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch \"my-local-cluster\" with kind StatefulSet: StatefulSet.apps \"my-local-cluster\" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy', 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden"
```

Why is that & how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Helm is trying to upgrade rather than install the chart, since you used `helm upgrade` rather than `helm install`. Like the error says, patching any field other than the ones listed is forbidden, but when you use `helm upgrade` I think it throws off the API. You might have already deployed it before and `--install` is messing with that, I am not entirely sure.

I suggest using `helm install` instead and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried using `helm install`, but yieds error `"Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot re-use a name that is still in use"`

Comment: And the answer in the link suggests to change back to `helm upgrade --install` like I am originally using. https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3134

Answer (score 0):

I think you applied the statefulset(sts) with the same name outside of helm. If you applied the sts with the `helm`, you could find the labels like:

```yaml
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
```

Just delete the sts that helm does not manage and run `helm upgrade` again.